# Duplication fields with nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, nested-forms, simple-form

I have polymorphic model `Images` and `Post`/`Account` etc.

models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  ...
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
end
```

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @post.images.build
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.images.build
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.images.build(params[:image])
    ...
  end

  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.images.build(params[:image])
    ...
  end
```

Form(simple_form)

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  ...
  = f.simple_fields_for :images do |i| 
    = i.input :photo, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: 'multiple', name: "image[][photo]"}, label: t(:photo)
  ...
  = f.submit class: "btn"
```

The problem is that when you create a post everything works fine, but when I want to edit this post, I can see the buttons with existing images and a button for a new image. 
[image]

How I can in edit form remove the button  for existing image and leave only the button for a new image. (Ideally, it would place the existing images with link to delete and button to attach new image). Thanks

Comment: did you try using `nested_form` gem  if you need remove links?

Comment: No, I have not heard about that gem. Thanks I will try that

Comment: Ok, `link_to_add/remove` its a good idea. But how I can render existing image instead a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer:

```
= f.fields_for :images do |i| 
    - if i.object.photo?
       = i.link_to_remove "Delete"
       = image_tag i.object.photo_url(:wide)
        %br
    - else
      = i.input :photo, as: :file, input_html: { multiple: 'multiple', name: "image[][photo]"}
```